# react-scripts build ignores conditional css imports

Tags: css, reactjs, build, scripting, conditional-statements

I am trying to conditionally require css for my react project and it works locally.
However, when the react-scripts build command is executed by react js all css files get bundled into one and the conditional import no longer works.

```
if(isSmartPhoneOrTablet()){
    require("./mobileStyle.css");
}else {
    require("./style.css");
}
```

`"build": "react-scripts build"`

Comment: Well that's literally just an if/else statement, so there's no way it can satisfy both conditions if just run once. Either that snippet is being run multiple times (and the condition outcome is changing), or the issue is somewhere else. Can you provide some relevant, basic info about the build configuration/process?

Comment: Sure, the npm run build command puts all the css into one file that the server uses. It does not seem to understand that some imports are conditional. In practice only one condition is executed (of course), but the problem occurs in the npm run build command which puts all the css into one file.

Comment: I'm....confused. How are you building (webpack?). And where are you doing this conditional importing? Is it within a component, or within your build script somewhere? Also, can you add the relevant code from your build script doing the CSS stuff.

Comment: The conditional importing is in all of my components (they each have their own css file). I added the build script above and I am not sure how I am building with webpack. I have not written any code to do with webpack.

Comment: Ok well then you won't be able to import from specific CSS files if those files don't exist after the app is built. They'd need to be kept separate rather than all combined into one big file. I'm not familiar with Heroku, but do you have access to that build script in the package.json? Or wherever it's combining the CSS into a single file?

Comment: Yes I wrote that line. The problem as I just tested is not to do with heroku and has totally to do with the react js npm run build command. After the npm run build command both css files get imported.

Comment: `npm run build` isn't related to react, it's just a command to the the 'build' script within `package.json`. Check and see what that command actually does, as in that script (or in some other script it runs) will be the code that's combining CSS files into 1

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will start looking into that

Comment: @jayce444 the build command actually runs react-scripts build, does this make more sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
var cssfile;
if(isSmartPhoneOrTablet()){
    cssfile = "./mobileStyle.css";
}else {
    cssfile = "./style.css";
}
require(cssfile);
```

Comment: @petermir Did this work for you? You have marked it as a correct answer.

Comment: No I use,if (isMobileOrTablet()) {
  module.exports = require("./mobileStyle.css");
} else {
  module.exports = require("./style.css");
}, but I had to change my build script to use webpack and create my own webpack configuration