# CRA - React production build with dynamic CSS imports

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

The issue:

Using the out-of-the-box react-scripts package included with create-react-app to build a production build of React, dynamically imported CSS files get ignored and instead all CSS seems to get compiled into the production build.

Example of what is happening:

```css
/* styles/desktop.css */
.some-class {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
/* styles/mobile.css */
.some-class {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1em;
}
.another-class {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

Note we are using require() with template strings as the import statement only accepts string literals and cssEnv could be any number of things which would make a conditional statement untenable.

```js
/* config.js */
const cssEnv = 'desktop';
require(`./styles/${cssEnv}.css`);
```

We build our production build.

`$ npm run build`

In the build folder, we find our compiled CSS. Note how all our CSS files have been compiled into one (including even CSS we never imported).

```css
/* compiledCSS.chunk.css */
.some-class {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
}
.another-class {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

A similar SO question I found in Googling for a solution:

[react-scripts build ignores conditional css imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50920391/react-scripts-build-ignores-conditional-css-imports)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm immediately answering my own question because I've already solved it, but also because I had a bit of a Homer Simpson "d'oh!" moment when I finally found the solution after scouring Google and documentation far and wide. This is why I posted the question, in hopes of saving other people that time searching for a solution that wasn't super obvious (and doesn't seem to be addressed anywhere that I have found).

So I didn't realize that the import statement had a dynamic importing functionality via import(). So the solution was simply to replace require() with import().

```js
/* config.js */
const cssEnv = 'desktop';
import(`./styles/${cssEnv}.css`);
```

Now when we build our production build, we get the correct compiled CSS

```css
/* compiledCSS.chunk.css */
.some-class {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
}
```

So my best guess as to what is happening is that react-scripts treats require() differently than import(), where providing a template string with variables to require() causes the variables to act like wildcards (*). So when we were building the production build earlier,

```js
require(`./styles/${cssEnv}.css`);
```

got treated like

```js
require(`./styles/*.css`);
```

Hence all css files in the styles folder were compiled together.

I'm not entirely sure of the intimate inner workings of what is happening here, so I wouldn't mind getting input from folks like Dan Abramov and others who might better understand what exactly is happening to clarify this.

Comment: Thank you! Was really struggling with this. Interestingly if you use a regular string with no variables in it doesn't seem to work - very weird!

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good solution. Doesn't work for me. Webpack will not always see dynamic css import in a CRA app. Some other package use css-loader to easily instruct webpack to add muliple css bundles during the build. I tried using your solution with .scss files...